# Right way to check if an object's prototype has given it a method

Tags: javascript

If an object prototype contains a specific method, I want to override it on the object/instance with a dummy. And I want to do this recursively, for all properties, objects and arrays inside this object.

What is the right way to check if an object's prototype has given it a method?

```
if('myInterestedMethod' in obj1){
   if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty('myInterestedMethod'){
      console.log('Method is from its prototype');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the properties by doing `for-in` and check if the value of each key is a `function`

```
 for ( var prop in obj1 )
 {
   if( !obj1.hasOwnProperty( prop ) && typeof obj1[ prop ] == "function" )
   {
      console.log( prop, 'Method is from its prototype');
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I know the method name, and would prefer to avoid iterating if possible..

Comment: Also, wondering if any spl treatment is required for array etc.

Comment: @Teddy there shouldn't be anything special required for array, since it may not have an inherited method at first place.